# PDF plot Matlab

Tags: matlab, pdf

I have fitted 1-D data with gaussian mixture model

```
X = 1000*1 observation data
gm = gmdistribution.fit(X,2);
```

And it gives,

```
gm = 

Gaussian mixture distribution with 2 components in 1 dimensions
Component 1:
Mixing proportion: 0.558547
Mean:   -0.0274

Component 2:
Mixing proportion: 0.441453
Mean:    0.1342
```

How can I plot 2 gaussians along with pdf of X?
Why are there only Means and no Sigmas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs you should be able to use the `pdf` function ans `ezplot` for this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gmdistribution.fit.html

Otherwise maybe try:

```
Y = pdf(gm, X);
plot(X,Y)
```

Comment: Doc uses 2-D data mine is 1-D, X is ECG data and I want to fit it's pdf so X can't be used as x axis on plot.